# Mocked class: methods hinting

Tags: mocking, phpunit, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have the following setup: I'm mocking non-abstract class with PHPUnit, but not all of it's methods. Therefore, non-mocked methods still exist as a call to real methods in the mock.

And the question is: how to hint that those methods are available (of course, with the proper signature) ?

I'll elaborate a bit. The sample of class:

```
class RealClass
{
    public function callApi(Api $api) {}

    public function doStuff(Foo $foo, Bar $bar) {}
}
```

Now I do in the test:

```
/** @var  \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $mock */
$mock = $this->getMock('\RealClass', ['callApi']);
```

This will create mock for `callApi()` only, but then if in the test I do:

```
$mock->doStuff($foo, $bar);
```

My PHPStorm can not find the method obviously and assumes this to be an error. How can I point that the `doStuff()` method exists and requires proper arguments?

`@method` seems to be working only within class definition. I tried to play a bit with `@see` but was unable to resolve the matter. Also, the ideal solution would be the one that allows to specify hinting also within return statements as I may want to return mocks from test helpers methods.

"Cheap cheat" is to hint with the original class, but that I do not want to do since then I will lose the point - which is mock and which is not. This especially is important since I'm using helpers to build complex entities where mocks are injected.

Answer (score 3):

You should hint the mock as either a `MockObject` or an instance of `RealClass`, so you'll get something like:

```
/** @var \RealClass|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $mock */
$mock = $this->getMock('\RealClass', ['callApi']);
```

Now you're telling PhpStorm that `$mock` can either be a PHPUnit `MockObject` *or* a `RealClass` instance and it will accept/autocomplete methods from either class.

Additionally (and this is just a friendly piece of advice and not at all necessary), you could use the `use` keyword to import the classes into your test class, so your hinting can become somewhat more readable:

```
<?php

use \RealClass;
use \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject as MockObject;

class YourTestClass
{
    public function yourTest()
    {
        // Because of the use statements (and the "as" alias rule) you can now:
        /** @var RealClass|MockObject $mock */
        $mock = $this->getMock('RealClass', ['callApi']);
    }
}
```

Comment: But then again - I will not be able to distinct whether it is mock or not in certain place. This is important since when I'm building stubs providers I need to know on a certain line - either the stuff is mocked or not. For now I'm just doing the distinction with naming (naming variables aka $fooMock, $barMock). So if that will be the case - then I'll just hint it with original class and that's it. Thanks for the answer, +1 anyways

Comment: When using mocks like this, only the `callApi` method is mocked out of the class, the other methods will be used from the real class, so you don't mock the entire class, just the method (and therefor should always know which one you're dealing with). Unless I misunderstood, but then maybe it's better to open a separate question with more details.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But imagine the case - yo need to distinct that the certain `$something` is mock or not. That `$something` was returned from some helper which I hinted `@return RealClass|MockObject`. Now - how to say, is it mock or not? Yes, it will assemble methods from both, but the identity of the entity itself is not clear. That's what I pointed to in the answer - and that's what I'm lacking now.

Comment: You can use [instanceof](http://php.net/instanceof) to achieve that. Like `if ($mock instanceof MockObject) { // It's the mock }` or `if ($mock instanceof RealClass) { // it's the real class }`.

Comment: Ehm.. no :) Because then I'll just name it like "$mockSomething"

Comment: Hmm, OK. Then I think it's best to open a separate question for this scenario, as I'm not really sure what the best approach would be.

Comment: If your tests rely on the mock being a real thing, your tests are broken and your mocking strategy is bad. I don't use partially mocked classes 99% of the time - and when I am forced to use some workaround, the reason is bad code written way before good testing practice came to life. Currently you have given no reason why you want a partial mock, and why you need to distinguish between real class or mock. I believe it should not matter at all.